# No HDMI sound in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I'm connected to a 40inch tv using HDMI and a green cable going from my computer to my Tvs auto port thing. This works on windows 10 windows 8 and windows 7. I switched back to Ubuntu 2 days ago because I want to start using Linux again.

I've tried re-installing and resetting Alsa and Pulse audio.
checked that it wasn't muted through alsamixer. Followed 2 pages of google searches copy pasting code into the terminal... I’m about to go back to windows.The sad thing is that I will have to pay for it again, even though I just had it. It seems this is a common problem with 14.04

Comment: What's a green cable, and how is it related to HDMI?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
Then go to search and type pulse 
open it
there in play back assuming you are playing in chromium 
select "High definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo"
Not it will work